Which mean to use for standard deviation: geometric or arithmetic?
Standard deviation is one common way of measuring an asset's volatility.  One component in calculating the standard deviation is the mean of the samples, and in most of the examples I can find, people use the arithmetic mean for this purpose.  But if you are averaging a set of year-over-year returns, (e.g. 1.01, 0.83, 1.12), would it be more sensible to use the geometric mean, since this number is more representative of the year-over-year return across all samples?

You should use the arithmetic average. While it's true that the geometric average is more useful for calculating average compounded return over a period, the volatility is more of a mathematical measure than a financial one, and is typically defined as the standard deviation, which is based on the normal distribution and uses arithmetic mean.
There is a separate formula for Geometric Standard Deviation that would apply if you used the geometric mean, but when measuring volatility the arithmetic standard deviation (and thus arithmetic average) is always used.
